# Execute JS from Rails controller

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, execjs

I want to call a javascript file at a remote location ( Like CDN's ). I want to call that JS File from a controller and should be able to call functions of that JS file and capture the output. I know [EXECJS](https://github.com/rails/execjs) can be used for that. I want to know how to specifically call a JS file on a remote location within the controller and execute functions.

Comment: Why do you need this?

Comment: Why don't you want to use ExecJS?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You can improve your question. Please read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) including the link "How to ask questions the smart way."

Comment: I'm ok using exec js. I want to know how can I achieve this using exec js. Thanks.